# Solidity on Remix IDE, Syntax Error: Free functions can not have visibility

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

I am trying to compile this code:

```js
pragma solidity  ^0.8.0; 
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

contract tonsofun {
    uint public i;
    bool public b;
    address public myAddress;
    }
    function foo() external {
        uint x = 123;
        bool f = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `foo()` function is outside the contract. and according to the [documentation](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2020/09/02/solidity-0.7.1-release-announcement/#:%7E:text=A%20free%20function%20behaves%20like,and%20in%20this%20case%2C%20msg.)

> A free function behaves like an internal function of the contract that
> called it.

therefore shouldnt not have the `external` visibility keyword.

Comment: When I remove "external" I get...SyntaxError: Free Functions cannot have visibility

Answer (score 1):

You said you removed the `external` keyword. Are you sure your code is like this?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TonsoFun { 
    uint public i;
    bool public b;
    address public myAddress;
}

function foo() { 
    uint x = 123;
    bool f = false;
}
```

I've tested this out and it's working fine.

In case you need more explanation on [free functions in solidity](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2020/09/02/solidity-0.7.1-release-announcement/#:%7E:text=A%20free%20function%20behaves%20like,and%20in%20this%20case%2C%20msg.)

Comment: contract tonsofun { 
    uint public i; 
    bool public b; 
    address public myAddress; 

///do not put a } after myAddress;
function foo() external { 
        uint x = 123; 
        bool f = false;

        i = 2;
        b = false;

        x = 44;
        f = true;
        myAddress = address (1);
    }

}

Comment: contract tonsofun { 
    uint public i; 
    bool public b; 
    address public myAddress; 

///do not put a } after myAddress;
function foo() external { 
        uint x = 123; 
        bool f = false;

        i = 2;
        b = false;

        x = 44;
        f = true;
        myAddress = address (1);
    }

}

Answer (score 1):

Richard, you were having issues with the curly brackets; you didn't place some correctly.

There should be no curly bracket after
"
address public myAddress;
}
"

Delete it. Then put another curly bracket after the enclosing curly bracket of the foo function.

This is what I am saying, everything should be like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity  ^0.8.0; 

contract tonsofun {
    uint public i;
    bool public b;
    address public myAddress;
    
    function foo() external {
        uint x = 123;
        bool f = false;
    }
}
```

Fixed